# "Positive systems" in n * the (n-1)-simplex

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let S := the nonnegative integer solutions to {$a_1 + ... + a_n = n$},
and center := (1,1,1,...,1).
Call a vector v generic if v.s = v.center <=> s = center.
Then each generic v defines a *positive system* in S,
the subset { s in S : v.s > v.center }.

Already at n=3 it is possible for one positive system to contain another.

Up to permutation, we may as well take v strictly decreasing.
Having done so, is there a reasonable way to classify 
the maximal positive systems?

Answer (score 3):

To make the obvious comment, $v$ and $w$ define the same positive system if they lie on the same side of $(s-c)^{\perp}$, where $s$ ranges through the noncentral points of the simplex and $c$ is the center. So your question is whether we can characterize the regions in the complement of this hyperplane arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace S by the lattice points in the positive orthant, and forget the condition that the hyperplane passes through a particular point, and require that the hyperplane only cuts off finitely many points, then you are looking at things called "corner cuts" by Onn and Sturmfels in [Cutting corners](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aama.1999.0645).

Anyway, I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe it'll suggest something.